# losing data while streaming on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, buffer

I am trying to stream a `csv` file from server tot he client. However, I am losing data in between the buffers.

client side

```
let data = '';
let count = 0;
$(document).ready(() => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/test/api', true);
    xhr.onprogress = function () {
        console.log('------- new buffer -------');
        let incomingBuffer = xhr.responseText;
        let splitbuffer = incomingBuffer.split(',')
        console.log('firsts')
        console.log(splitbuffer[0])
        console.log(splitbuffer[1])

        console.log('lasts')
        console.log(splitbuffer[splitbuffer.length - 2])
        console.log(splitbuffer[splitbuffer.length - 1])

};
xhr.send()
});
```

server side

```
app.get('/test/api', (req, res) => {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('./resources/onescsv.csv');
    stream = byline.createStream(stream);
    stream.pipe(res);
    stream.on('end', () => res.end());

});
```

the data that I am streaming is a csv file that has identical 10,000 rows and have columns increasing by one starting from 1 until 32. So each row has 1, 2, 3,... 32.

When I run this application, I get

```
------- new buffer -------
test.js:21 firsts
test.js:22 1
test.js:23 2
test.js:25 lasts
test.js:26 2
test.js:27 3
------- new buffer -------
test.js:21 firsts
test.js:22 1
test.js:23 2
test.js:25 lasts
test.js:26 31
test.js:27 32
```

The first buffer is going full at 3 but the new buffer is starting from 1 again - it should be starting from 4 and increment to 32 and loop through from 1 to 32 and so on. So I am losing data in between 4 and 32.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I actually have multiple buffers showing up on the client but they ALL start from 1 no matter where it ends in the last buffer.

CSV content

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
```

The above is only 10 lines but that is repeated to 10,000 lines

The client output when I delete byline and add columns up to 58

```
------- new buffer -------
test.js:21 firsts
test.js:22 1
test.js:23 2
test.js:25 lasts
test.js:26 49
test.js:27 50
------- new buffer -------
test.js:21 firsts
test.js:22 1
test.js:23 2
test.js:25 lasts
test.js:26 57
test.js:27 58
------- new buffer -------
test.js:21 firsts
test.js:22 1
test.js:23 2
test.js:25 lasts
test.js:26 39
test.js:27 40
------- new buffer -------
test.js:21 firsts
test.js:22 1
test.js:23 2
test.js:25 lasts
test.js:26 57
test.js:27 58
```

snapshot of last part of the second buffer's text

```
9,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
test.js:27 firsts
test.js:28 1
test.js:29 2
test.js:31 lasts
test.js:32 50
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the CSV. Just a sample.

Comment: @LuckySoni I have updated thanks

Comment: 'byline.createStream(stream);' sends one full row at a time? Could you console.log the incomingBuffer variable and post result?

Comment: @LuckySoni I am streaming line by line because I need to know where the positions of new line. If the buffer stops before a new line, I won't be able to tell that.

Comment: @LuckySoni I have updated the output after removing by line. I'm still losing data

Comment: @LuckySoni also added columns up to 58

Comment: Could you do a console.log(incomingBuffer) just after the 'let incomingBuffer = xhr.responseText' and post the result? Also dont delete the byline thing.

Comment: @LuckySoni hang on. I have logged too much that it is very laggy

Comment: @LuckySoni it does end with 50 so lost some data